# incorrect teredo ipv6 address advertising

Tags: bitcoind

I have an issue with teredo addresses. After network issues or router reconnect the teredo tunneling interface address changes but bitcoind stays still unaware of it and continues to advertise the old (incorrect) ipv6 address.
Should I raise the issue on github on this?
Can somebody check if this exists on regular (not teredo) ipv6 interface?

Thanks.